# Failed to load resource picture after create in index page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hello I'm trying to add an image to my database from local folder  and is working successfully but is saved with path and is `not displaying` no image  on Index page but is `created value path` on database
I have this error :

> GET http://localhost:57079/'~/Content/img/Asp.net.svg.png'

This is create Mothod :

```
public ActionResult Create( Article article,HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
    {

        try
        {
            db = new IdentityDBEntities2();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (postedFile != null)
                {

                    article.image = Convert.ToString(postedFile.ContentLength);
                    postedFile.InputStream.Read(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(article.image), 0, postedFile.ContentLength);
                    string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
                    string FilePath = "~/Content/img/" + fileName;
                    postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(FilePath));
                }

                article.UserId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
                article.Idc = Convert.ToInt32(Request["cab"]);
                db.Articles.Add(article);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(article);
        }
        catch(Exception e) { Response.Write(e.Message); }
        return View();
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An image is saved as a byte array in a database. So your call

```
article.image = Convert.ToString(postedFile.ContentLength);
```

makes no sense if you want to save the actual image. You would need to do something like this:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif); //Specify format here; (image is of type System.Drawing.Image)
article.image = ms.ToArray();
```

Your image property needs to be of type `byte[]` and the underlying database column needs to be `VARBINARY`.

EDIT: You are getting an error because `image` needs to be of type `System.Drawing.Image` as stated in the comments. If you can't use this (or don't want to) you need to extract byte array from 'HttpPostedFileBase' like so:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
postedFile.InputStream.CopyTo(ms); 
article.image = ms.ToArray();
```

When you have done all this, you can display the image on your View like this:

1. Create a new action that returns the image for each article

   `public ActionResult GetImage(int id)
   {
       var article = db.Articles.First(i => i.Id == id);
       return File(article.image, "image/png"); //Adjust content type based on image type (jpeg, gif, png, etc.)
   }`
2. Replace the code on your View so it gets the image from that action.

   Change

   ```
   `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.image, new {htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" ,@type="file" } }`
   ```

   to

   ```
   `<img src="@Url.Action("Index", "Images", new { id = Model.Id })" />`
   ```

Take note that this won't make the image editable. You better ask a new question if you need this functionality as this answer already goes beyond what your original question was about.

Comment: Yes is true but  where i get value of `image.Save` because i do all thing u sayd but is give me error on that line thanks